# C - Assigning heap memory to Global variable

Tags: c, memory-leaks, global-variables

Suppose I have an shared library file (say libtemp.so) which has a global variable. If I dynamically load this library, assign a heap memory to it, and then close the library. If I load the library again, then is the old heap memory leaked? (I think its true since global variables will be reset when the library is loaded again)

Is it a bad practice to assign heap memory to a global variable? Are there any cases where we end up having to do this?

Comment: It is just bad practice to not clean up your own dynamic allocations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, the library global variable sits in some data segment of the shared object, and that segment would have been `munmap`-ed when `dlclose`-ing the `libtemp.so` and would have been `mmap`-ed again at the next `dlopen` so the global would have been reinitialized.

(I am assuming you are doing only one single `dlopen` i.e. that the `libtemp.so` is not `dlopen`-ed twice)

BTW, you could do initialization in constructor functions (and finalization in destructor), see [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in GCC. The constructors are executed at `dlopen`time, and the destructors at `dlclose` time. Read also Linux [dlopen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) man page for details. (Notice that POSIX [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) don't have these tricks)

Comment: Yes, it does, and the dtors will only run (and the ctors will only get re-run on next load) if the library was actually unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It's implementation-specific whether unloading and reloading the library will reset global variables or not. In any case, it's bad practice to have any global variables whatsoever, especially in shared libraries. The most common usage case for the sort of thing you're talking about is having global tables that are calculated at initialization time. Instead you should just replace them with `static const` tables stored in the binary file.